# CakePhp3.x Update Join Table in a Has Many Relationship

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I was searching for hours and the documentation of CakePhp3 is not very clear for me.

I have an app for reading an XML and the data is saved or updated to CakePHP 3

I have three models (Properties - Tags - OriginalImages) joined by a Has Many Relationship (I am not using ManyToMany relationship because I need another field throughout). When I create a property with new Tags, I don't have problems. The property is added correctly and the tags as well.

```
class PropertyTagsTable extends Table
```

{

```
/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('property_tags');
    $this->setDisplayField('name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Properties', [
        'foreignKey' => 'properties_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

class PropertiesTable extends Table
{

```
/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('properties');
    $this->setDisplayField('name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('ImagesAffiliates', [
        'foreignKey' => 'property_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('OriginalImages', [
        'foreignKey' => 'property_id'
    ]); 
    $this->hasMany('PropertyTags', [
        'foreignKey' => 'property_id'
    ]);
}
```

The problem happens when I try to update the join data, because CakePHP always thinks that the new data are new tags, adding the tags again to the property_tags table.

For Example, when I create a Property with ID=20 I add the tags, Pool and Garage. If I run the script for reading the XML again I want to modify the property data (for example the price, this is working) but If the tag pool exists, don't write it again, but if there is a new tag (for example, BBQ) add it. The outcome that I need will be

Property id=20 with tags, Pool, Garage, and BBQ. However, I got property id=20 with Pool, Garage, BBQ, Pool, Garage.

I solved manually this problem deleting all tags when I update again the Property, but I think that this is not the smart way to do it so avoiding to repeat the tag?

Can I make a method for comparing each tag with the existent one or CakePhp3.0 has some way to do it?

I think the problem is like the data is in another place different to the database I cannot associate the XML Tag with the existent in the db creating new elements to the entity.

```
            $properties = $this->loadModel('Properties');
        $query = $properties->find('all')->where( ['listing_identifier' => $xmlProperty["listing_identifier"] ] );

        if ( $query->first() <> NULL ){ //Exists we update the data

            $property = $query->first();

            $property = $this->Properties->get($property->id, [
                    'contain' => ['OriginalImages', 'PropertyTags']
                ]); 


            $this->Properties->PropertyTags->deleteAll( [ 'property_id' => $property->id ] );       //Deleting manually the tags.

            try {   
                $property2 = $this->Properties->patchEntity(  $property, $xmlProperty, ['associated'=>['PropertyTags', 'OriginalImages'] ] ); 

                $this->Properties->save( $property  ); //Update
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {

            }
        }
        else { //Not exists we create a new one property

            $property = $this->Properties->patchEntity($property, $xmlProperty, [
                'associated' => ['OriginalImages', 'PropertyTags'] ]);      

            $property = $this->Properties->save( $property );
```

Comment: What about the association of Tags model with Properties_Tags?

Comment: Finally I had to set the ids up manually before patchEntity. Is the only way that I found to fix this.